# Using stepAIC to make out of sample predictions

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

just had a quick question on using Step AIC to make prediction. I'm a beginner in R, so please pardon if the solution is obvious. Tried searching around but couldn't really find what I was looking for.

So I'm trying to predict the response variable, after running stepwise AIC on a main model (main model has all the explanatory variables). The stepAIC gives out a new model that has a reduced number of variables. My question is how do I do an out of sample prediction using the new reduced model. In other words, how does I reduce the dataset so that when I feed it into predict.lm, it only has the variables that were selected in the reduced model.

Here's my code below:

---

```
# Specify start and end row of the first 5 year window
start_row=1
end_row=60

#declare matrix that will contain the predicted returns by specifying dimensions
predicted=matrix(0,179,7)

y_var=as.matrix(orig_data[start_row:end_row,2:7])
x_var=as.matrix(orig_data[start_row:end_row,8:27])

# Perform linear regression on all factors and then select factors using stepwise AIC     method

initial_model<-    lm(y_var[,1]~x_var[,1]+x_var[,2]+x_var[,3]+x_var[,4]+x_var[,5]+x_var[,6]+x_var[,7]+x_var[,8]+x_var[,9]+x_var[,10]+x_var[,11]+x_var[,12]+x_var[,13]+x_var[,14]+x_var[,15]+x_var[,16]+x_var[,17]+x_var[,18]+x_var[,19]+x_var[,20])

reduced_model<-stepAIC(initial_model, direction="both")
reduced_coefs<-t(as.matrix(coef(reduced_model)))
x_input<-as.matrix(x_var[60,])
```

---

Basically how do I multiply the coefficients that I get from the reduced model to only the corresponding explanatory variables in "x_var" (which has all the explanatory variables)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In principle something like `predict(reduced_model,newdata=x_input)` *except that* there are going to be some complexities due to (1) your multiple response variables and (2) the fact that you're not using a `data` argument.  If you give a **reproducible** example I might take a crack at this.